# mysql replication: remove consumed logs

Tags: database-replication, mysql

I have a master mysql server with only one attached slave.

I have configured my master server to keep logs for 2 day, but in a simple configuration like mine is possible to configure an environment where master logs are deleted as soon as be consumed by the ONLY ONE slave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no option for what you're describing.

The reason is that replication is *asynchronous*. The source has no idea how many replicas are subscribed, it only knows which replicas are connected at any given time. That is, a replica could be offline and expect to reconnect and resume reading binlogs where it left off.

The only option in stock MySQL for binary log expiration is the config variable `config_logs_days`.

Percona Server adds [another option](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/flexibility/max_binlog_files.html), to expire binlogs if the number of files is more than `max_binlog_files`. This helps to avoid running out of disk space if you have a short burst of heavy traffic before `expire_logs_days` causes old logs to be expired.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Utilities includes a command line tool to purge binlogs on a master that have been consumed by slaves.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqlbinlogpurge.html